# Can you rewrite the QCD lagrangian in terms of hadron?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, quantum-chromodynamics, hadron-dynamics

Is it possible to (exactly) rewrite the QCD lagrangian in terms of hadrons?

I get that it's probably practically too difficult to do, but would it be possible in principle?

Comment: 1. In the low-energy limit, chiral perturbation theory is the low-energy effective field theory of QCD. It is formulated in terms of the asymptotic fields of QCD (hadrons). For details, see the well known seminal publications by S. Weinberg and J. Gasser, H. Leutwyler. 2. A single quark "state" $|u\rangle$ does not exist (as a physical state). The question does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

By "exactly" you seem to imply "directly", or ab initio. People have built bridges between fundamental QCD on the lattice and σ-models summarizing chiral symmetry breaking for pseudoscalar mesons, other mesons, and baryons. For decades, KG Wilson and GP Lepage were  promising to provide such a crucial bridge, but it did not come to pass... In any case, Wilson's basic philosophy of effective lagrangians dictates that there *be* such a bridge, even as a desideratum, after integrating out short-distance quark and gluon degrees of freedom, to be left with hadrons and their couplings. So, yes, *in principle* such a transition is universally accepted as an article of faith, but practically chimerical.

In our times, there is enormous practical contentment  with chiral perturbation theory, a more selective technique, producing wildly successful effective hadronic lagrangians. You might get a good trail-map in this review by G Ecker, [***Chiral perturbation theory***](https://doi.org/10.1016/0146-6410(95)00041-G),
*Progress in Particle and Nuclear Physics*, **35** (1995) 1-80.